# How to show two DataBase's in one Page - Crystal-Report ? (C#)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to two DataBase's in one Page using Crystal-Report ?

i work with C# VS2008

ex. i have 2 Dataset (dsView1 and dsView2) and i want to show in one Crystal-Report page

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. create a report; don't supply a data source.  Add formatting (e.g. logo, page numbering)
2. insert a subreport using 1st DataSet.  Don't link main/subreport.
3. insert a subreport using 2nd DataSet.  Don't link main/subreport.
4. save/run report